# VS Code Formatting - script type

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the following HTML:

[image: different lines]

The problem is that when I add `type=""` everything formats to the same line of code like the image below.

[image: array is on same line]

Comment: Please add the code blocks as text in the question, not as images.

Comment: @shehanpathirathna I actually think that the images are better here since it's just a question about the formatting and we don't need to alter the code at all to answer. What confuses me is that both images have entirely different JavaScript, how does 1 format to 2 Joao?

Comment: @ZachJensz Agree

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the combination: Alt+Shift+F ?

Comment: Doesn't work. The problem was some extension conflict, I removed most of them and now it works. Thank you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the plugin "prettier" to VSCode to format the code easily. It will auto format your code on save. You can also change the default style configurations if only needed. Please checkout following link. [https://www.codereadability.com/automated-code-formatting-with-prettier/#:~:text=Install%20the%20Prettier%20VS%20Code,once%20the%20installation%20is%20complete](https://www.codereadability.com/automated-code-formatting-with-prettier/#:%7E:text=Install%20the%20Prettier%20VS%20Code,once%20the%20installation%20is%20complete).